# Get username and password from http git URL

Tags: regex, git, servlets

I have my own custom git servlet implemented using GitServlet.
I have my own authentication.

To clone or push, pull i want to authenticate against my authentication plugin.
To do this i need to read user/password from url given by user.

Like,

```
git clone  http://sohanb:welcome@localhost:8080/git.ctr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/portal/.git
```

How can i get the usernmae i.e sohanb and password i.e welcome.

**Updated question:**

My git init code,

```
 public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {  

    username = config.getInitParameter("username");
    password=config.getInitParameter("password");
    idpUrl=config.getInitParameter("idpUrl");
    System.out.println("IDP URL is =======>> " + idpUrl);
    setRepositoryResolver(new RepositoryResolver<HttpServletRequest>() {
        public Repository open(HttpServletRequest req, String name) throws RepositoryNotFoundException,
                ServiceNotEnabledException {
            try {
                System.out.println("name =============>> " +name);
                System.out.println("parmrs if any ==========>> " + req.getParameterMap());                  
                System.out.println("URL ===============>>" + req.getRequestURL().toString());
                URL url  = new URL(req.getRequestURL().toString());
                System.out.println("Trying to get uswer info if any ====>> " +url.getUserInfo());
                File gitParentFolder = new File("D:\\sigma-admin\\git.ctr\\git");
                File gitRepoFolder = new File(gitParentFolder, name);
                System.out.println("gitRepoFolder.exists() =======>>" + gitRepoFolder.exists());
                if (gitRepoFolder.exists()) {
                    if (!gitRepoFolder.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".git")) {
                        gitRepoFolder = new File(gitRepoFolder, ".git");
                    }
                    Repository db = Git.open(gitRepoFolder).getRepository();
                    db.incrementOpen();
                    return db;
                } else {
                    throw new RepositoryNotFoundException("Unknown repository was requested by client " + name);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RepositoryNotFoundException(name, e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My git war running under jettry server

```
http://localhost:8080/git.ctr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/
```

Now when i do `git clone  http://sohanb:welcome@localhost:8080/git.ctr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/portal/.git`
The url i can see in logs/console,

```
http://localhost:8080/git.ctr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/portal/.git/
```

I don't know why use:pass missing from req url. Or it is not valid what i am trying to achieve.

Other suggestion to do this are most welcomed. 
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

A regex would be:

```
https?:\/\/(?<user>[^:]+):(?<password>[^@]+)
# look for http or https followed by ://
# capture everything up (but not including) a colon and capture it in a group called user
# match a colon
# capture everything up (but not including) an @ and capture it in a group called password
```

See a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gD2qQ5/1) here. It however somewhat depends on what you really want (working with the information in PHP, Python, the bash, etc.).

Comment: In servelet how do i get the URL. I am running under jetty. When i do req.getRequestURL().toString() i just get  http://localhost:8080/git.ctr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/dashboard-portal/.git/info/refs. I cannot see username:password carrying in URL. 

What method of servelt should be useful here?

Answer (score -1):

Since it is `http:`, you can use the `java.net.URL`:

```
URL url = new URL("http://sohanb:welcome@localhost:8080/git.ctr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/portal/.git");
String userInfo = url.getUserInfo(); // userInfo = "sohanb:welcome"
```

Check for null and then you can get what you want really easy:

```
String[] userInfoArray = userInfo.split(":");
String username = userInfoArray[0]; // sohanb
String password = userInfoArray[1]; // welcome
```

Comment: reuqest url i am getting is http://localhost:8080/git.ctr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/dashboard-portal/.git/info/refs.
I expect the incoming url http://sohanb:welcome@localhost:8080/git.ctr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/portal/.git

user/pass passed in url is missing. I am not sure what is wrong . The war is deployed under servelet.